# Binding RadGrid To DataTable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik

What i am trying to do is that before saving records to database i want to show the records in GridView that is when user fill the text box and click on button the record is to be shown on GridView with serial Number 1 , 2 , 3 ... 
So far i have approach this . The first records get added successfully but when adding second record the DataTable give null reference exception . Is this the right approach ? Or is there an easy way to do this . I am using Telerik RadGrid for asp.net .

```
 public DataTable dt;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Sn#");
            dt.Columns.Add("type");
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountTitle");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");
            dt.Columns.Add("CostCenter");
            dt.Columns.Add("Debit");
            dt.Columns.Add("Credit");
            sno.Text = "1";
        }

    }

  protected void radGridView2_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
            dt = AddRow(dt);  // call the method to create row 
            ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
            radGridView2.DataSource = dt;      
    }

    private DataTable AddRow(DataTable dt)
    { // method to create row

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = sno.Text;
            dr[1] = type.Text;
            dr[2] = htitle.Text;
            dr[3] = disc.Text;
            dr[4] = job.SelectedItem.Text;
            dr[5] = drr.Text;
            dr[6] = crr.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        return dt;
    }  



    protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];       
        ViewState["dt"] = AddRow(dt);
        radGridView2.Rebind();
        Session["cttt"] = Convert.ToInt32(sno.Text)+1;
        sno.Text = Session["cttt"].ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: On which line are you getting null point exception

Comment: private DataTable AddRow(DataTable dt)
    { // method to create row

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();   on this line bro

Comment: Not 100% sure --- but in page_load write else of if(!IsPostBack){...} else {DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];}

Comment: Still showing the same exception . :(

Answer (score 1):

I have copy your code and change a bit. Due to your `dt` declared twice. I believe your error will be the `DataTable` is `null`

.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rg" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"></telerik:RadGrid>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="sno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="type" runat="server" Text="A"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="htitle" runat="server" Text="B"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="disc" runat="server" Text="C"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="job" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>Yeah</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="drr" runat="server" Text="D"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="crr" runat="server" Text="E"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="b1_Click" />

    </div>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

.cs

```
private DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        sno.Text = "1";
    }
}

private DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Sn#");
    dt.Columns.Add("type");
    dt.Columns.Add("AccountTitle");
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");
    dt.Columns.Add("CostCenter");
    dt.Columns.Add("Debit");
    dt.Columns.Add("Credit");

    return dt;
}

private DataTable AddRow(DataTable dt1)
{ // method to create row

    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
    dr[0] = sno.Text;
    dr[1] = type.Text;
    dr[2] = htitle.Text;
    dr[3] = disc.Text;
    dr[4] = job.SelectedItem.Text;
    dr[5] = drr.Text;
    dr[6] = crr.Text;
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt1;
}  

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    rg.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;    
}

protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt1 = ViewState["dt"] != null ? ViewState["dt"] as DataTable : CreateDataTable();
    ViewState["dt"] = AddRow(dt1);
    rg.Rebind();
    Session["cttt"] = Convert.ToInt32(sno.Text) + 1;
    sno.Text = Session["cttt"].ToString();
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: ViewState["dt"] = AddRow(dt); just changed this line to ViewState["dt"] = AddRow(dt1); in b1_Click and it is working great

Comment: Great Loved it :) You owe me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860285/changing-datasourceid-of-a-dropdown-from-javascript can you look at this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a variable with the same name as the global variable (dt) in the event b1_click - this is causing the confusion and the error.

```
protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Use the global variable dt
    //DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];       
    dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];       
    ViewState["dt"] = AddRow(dt);
    radGridView2.Rebind();   //Note this would call the NeedDataSource event
    Session["cttt"] = Convert.ToInt32(sno.Text)+1;
    sno.Text = Session["cttt"].ToString(); 
}
```

Another point to note here is that the AddRow method will be called twice on the button click. Once from b1_click event and then again from NeedDataSource event (which gets triggered on radGridView2.Rebind())