# Changing DataSourceId of a dropdown from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can i change the DataSourceID of a drop down depending on my dropdown selection in javascript i got three dropdown value on the base of selection of dropdown i want to change the datasource of SqlDataSource

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function abc() {
            if (document.getElementById('type').value == "C") {

            }

           else if (document.getElementById('type').value == "G") {

            }
           else if (document.getElementById('type').value == "S") {

            }
        }
    </script>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="type" runat="server" onblur ="abc();">
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>G</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>S</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource
          id="C"
          runat="server"
          DataSourceMode="DataReader"
          ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnString%>"
          SelectCommand="select rtrim(customer) as customer,cust_id from a1_customer where isactive=1 order by customer">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:SqlDataSource
          id="G"
          runat="server"
          DataSourceMode="DataReader"
          ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnString%>"
          SelectCommand="select rtrim(supplier) as supplier,sup_id from a1_supplier where isactive=1  order by supplier">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource
          id="S"
          runat="server"
          DataSourceMode="DataReader"
          ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnString%>"
          SelectCommand="select rtrim(title) as title ,acno,ac_type from a1_glcard where isactive=1 and levels=4 order by title">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="htitle" runat="server" DataSourceID="C" DataTextField="customer" DataValueField="cust_id"  Width="168px">
```

Comment: Must use `Javascript`? and putting out `SQL Select statement` like this will get a lot trouble on security.

Comment: If you prefer javascript to do it then just refer on this... I'm not familiar with javascript binding....
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-using-JavaScript-and-ASP.Net-AJAX.aspx

Comment: If i set datasource from code behind and change the value of one combo depending on other it take times to load on postback .

Comment: Well it won't be long...You just set the `DataSourceID` and `rebind` it... Put an `UpdatePanel` will eliminate the `postback` effect. I also believe the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` should be same since you are using `javascript` ?

Comment: no both are different . In that case i think updatepanel is best choice